# How do I record all child processes spawned by an Ant script over time?

Tags: bash, ant, child-process

I inherited a legacy Ant-based build system and I'm trying to get a sense of its scope. I observed multiple `jvm` and `junit` tasks with `fork=yes`. It calls `subant` and similar tasks wildly. Occasionally, it just `exec`s other processes.

I really don't want to search through 100s of scripts and reference documentation for every task to find possible-forking-behavior. I'd like to capture the child-process list while the build runs.

I managed to create a clean Vagrant + Puppet environment for builds and I can run the full build like so

```
$ cd /vagrant && $ANT_HOME/bin/ant
```

If I had to brute force something... I'd have a script kick off the build and capture child processes until the build is completed?

```
#!/bin/bash

$ANT_HOME/bin/ant &
while ps $!
do
  sleep 1
  ps --ppid $! >> build_processes
done
```

Comment: Is this linux? Could you consider strace -f  -e trace=fork ant ...

Comment: I am running on CentOS 7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Jayan recommended `strace`, specifically:

```
$ strace -f -e trace=fork ant
```

The `-f` limits tracing to `fork` system calls.

> Trace child processes as they are  created  by  cur-
>                      rently  traced  processes as a result of the fork(2)
>                      system call.  The new process is attached to as soon
>                      as  its  pid  is  known (through the return value of
>                      fork(2) in the parent process). This means that such
>                      children  may  run  uncontrolled  for a while (espe-
>                      cially in the case of a vfork(2)), until the  parent
>                      is  scheduled again to complete its (v)fork(2) call.
>                      If the parent process decides to wait(2) for a child
>                      that  is  currently  being  traced,  it is suspended
>                      until an appropriate child process either terminates
>                      or  incurs a signal that would cause it to terminate
>                      (as determined from the child’s current signal  dis-
>                      position).

I can't find the `trace=fork` expression, but `trace=process` seems useful.

```
-e trace=process
```

> Trace all system calls which involve process management.   This  is useful for watching the fork, wait, and exec steps of a process.

http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/strace1.html

Answer (score 0):

As ant is a java process, you can try to use [byteman](http://byteman.jboss.org/). In byteman script you define rules which are triggered when methods `exec` from `java.lang.Runtime` are executed.

You attach byteman to ant using `ANT_OPTS` env variable.